# Read image files on s3 with a total size of 4GB into numpy

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-s3

I am trying to read about 5,000 files (4GB total size) in different folders and load them into a numpy array but I keep getting memory issues.

Heres my code

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket('data-test')
objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='myprefix')
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
np_arr = np.zeros((len(cc),256,256,12))
for i, label in enumerate(cc):
    print(label)
    imgg = np.zeros((12, 256,256))
    for b, file in enumerate(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix = 'data_test/folder/{label}'.format(label=label))):
        print('-----{file}------'.format(file=file))
        file_name=file.key
        response = file.get()
        file_stream = response['Body']
        print('--------About to read image in {label} ----'.format(label=label))
        im = Image.open(file_stream)
        img_arr = np.array(im)
        imgg[b] = img_arr
        del img_arr
    imgg = np.swapaxes(imgg, 0, 2)
    np_arr[i] = imgg
    del imgg

h5f = h5py.File('data.h5', 'w')
print('hfc opened')
h5f.create_dataset('dataset', data=np_arr)
print('h5f created')
h5f.close()
```

Jupyter notebook restarts after about an hour and it freezes the system.

Cant find the solution to that.
My system has 16gb of ram

Comment: You're sure you need them all in a single numpy array in RAM? You could probably concatenate them into a file on disk and avoid loading them all into memory simultaneously.

Comment: Do you have an example of how the data you try to process looks like?

Comment: And it'd be great to know what you intend to achieve with that code.

Comment: @William do you suggest I write each of the np_arr arrays to a file?

Comment: @Dunedan its image files which I am working with. Im trying to train a model using the images

Comment: use h5py instead

Comment: @yanziselman I intend on doing that when the np_arr array is fully loaded. The problem is I am trying to load The array first